# Failed to Fetch for JPEG Downloads from Amazon S3 in Angular App on Chrome and Brave Browsers

Tags: angular, google-chrome, amazon-s3, chromium

I have this issue when I download jpeg image from amazon S3 on my anguar app in Chrome and Brave (brave is chromium browser). This issue not happen with pdf.

```
   TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at zone-evergreen.js:1068:1
    at Utils.downloadResource (Utils.ts:103:5)
    at LecteurDocComponent_Template_img_click_14_listener (template.html:11:90)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14293:1)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14328:1)
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27126:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
(anonymous) @ Utils.ts:114
```

This is my code :

downloadResource(filename: String) {

```
this.url = this.changeSpecialCharacter(this.urlFolder + filename);
let extention = this.getFileExtension(filename);

filename = this.getFileName(filename);

if (!filename.includes(extention)) {
  filename = filename + '.' + extention;
}

if (!filename) filename = this.url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
fetch(this.url, {
  headers: new Headers({
    'Origin': location.origin
  }),
  mode: 'cors'
})
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    let blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.forceDownload(blobUrl, filename);
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

}

and this is my CORS configuration in Amazon S3

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*",
        "capacitor://localhost"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]